# JScript Array issue

Tags: javascript, arrays, com, jscript

**Reposted working code**

(I'm trying to get Arrays from my ActiveX component, but with no luck. When I run the script I get empty Message Box, but I know that the Array are there:)

```
var objMain, objAdapt, lgCount, stMsg = "";

objMain = new ActiveXObject("nnetcom.oMain");

objMain.UnlockComponent("xxx-xxxxx-xxxxx-xx");

objAdapt = new ActiveXObject("nnetcom.oNetworkAdapter");

objAdapt.GetNetworkAdapters(); // Collects Network Adapters

vrAdapters = objAdapt.cName; // cName holds collected Network Adapter names

var vrAdaptVB = new VBArray(vrAdapters);

var vrAdaptJS = vrAdaptVB.toArray();

for (lgCount in vrAdaptJS) {
  stMsg = stMsg + vrAdaptJS[lgCount] + '\r\n'; 
}

WScript.Echo(stMsg);

objAdapt = null
objMain = null
```

Comment: Using vrAdapt[lgCount] is just invalid.  Surely you meant `stMsg = stMsg + lgCount + '\r\n';`  Or the array is just empty, quite possible if the original code didn't bomb.

Comment: objAdapt.cName has inside 18 entry but I don't know how to enumerate dynamic arrays in my case...I'm not in JScripting, I just know a little bit of it...so, can you help me out whit my little script...to enumerate dynamic array data from **objAdapt.cName**?

Comment: Can you provide the structure of what cName looks like?  Is it really just a string?

Comment: @Rake36 I already solved myself this issue, you can see my answer at the bottom of the page. Its not a String Array, its a Variant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Or simplest way from my first posted answer would be:**

```
var vrAdaptVB = new VBArray(vrAdapters);

var vrAdaptJS = vrAdaptVB.toArray();

stMsg = "";

for (lgCount in vrAdaptJS) {
 stMsg = stMsg + vrAdaptJS[lgCount] + '\r\n'; 
}
```

**This example also works fine for me!**

[image: List Network Adapters working example]

Answer (score 2):

```
var vrAdaptVB = new VBArray(vrAdapters);

var vrAdaptJS = vrAdaptVB.toArray();

stMsg = "";

for (lgCount = 0; lgCount < vrAdaptJS.length; ++lgCount) {
 stMsg = stMsg + vrAdaptJS[lgCount] + '\r\n';
}
```

Comment: It would help future visitors if you could add an explanation of _why_ this fixed the issue.

Comment: @CheranShunmugavel What I figured out...An Array object in JScript is not the same as a VBScript array. In JScript the data type is called a "VBArray" (also referred to as a "safearray"). Probably the easiest way to iterate a VBArray object is to return a JScript Array copy of the VBArray object using the Array object's constructor or the Array object's toArray() method.

Answer (score 0):

Per Hans comment,

```
for (lgCount in vrAdapt)
{
    stMsg = stMsg + vrAdapt[lgCount] + '\r\n';
}
```

should be:

```
for (lgCount in vrAdapt)
{
    stMsg = stMsg + lgCount + '\r\n';
}
```

as lgCount is the element, not the index.

My Mistake.  This example works:

```
var list = {a:1,b:2,c:3,d:4,e:5};
var msg = "";
for (i in list) {
    msg = msg + list[i]; 
}
//msg = 12345

msg = "";
for (i in list) {
    msg = msg + i; 
}
//msg = abcde

var list = [1,2,3,4,5];
msg = "";
for (i in list) {
    msg = msg + i; 
}
//msg = 01234

msg = "";
for (i in list) {
    msg = msg + list[i]; 
}
//msg = 12345
```

Comment: Maybe you are right about that, I changed the code above, but it doesn't return me nothing, I got the same source in VBScript and its working great! Can you tell me what is the problem now in the code?

Comment: This is wrong.  `lgCount` will be an array index (or a property name, if the array has extra properties added to it).  See the MSDN page for [`for..in`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/55wb2d34%28VS.84%29.aspx), specifically "Before each iteration of a loop, _variable_ is assigned the next property name of _object_ or the next element index of _array_."

Comment: My bad Cheran.  Appended an example.

Comment: @Rake36 Maybe its working in your case in simple java example, but in my case doesn't working, returns empty in **msg**, I must use **VBArray** then **toArray()** to be able to get everything right! And its working now!